# How do I position my images in a "scattering" form so that they appear well on smaller screens?

Tags: html, css, image

I want to position 5 different images behind text in a scattering fashion like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laqI8.jpg)

Here is the code that I have so far:

```html
<section id="about" style="position:relaitve">
  <div style="position:absolute; z-index:5">
    <h2 id="dreambig" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="700" data-aos-easing="ease-in" data-aos-once="true">Dream Big.</h2>
    <p  id="dbt" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-easing="ease-in" data-aos-once="true" data-aos-delay="50" style="font-size: 225%; margin-left: 7%; margin-right: 20%; color: #706d69; margin-bottom: 2%; font-weight: bold"><span style="color:#fff">We all dream.</span> Maybe you wanted to become a doctor. A research scientist. An astronomer. A mathematician. But oftentimes, in your curious pursuit for knowledge, no one was there to guide you. Maybe no one was there to teach you college-level physics when you really wanted to become an engineer, and you gave up on your dream. This is a big problem. <span style="color:#fff">Well, not so much anymore with Pandorax.</span> </p>
  </div>
  <div id="dbi" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1000" data-aos-easing="ease-in" data-aos-once="true" data-aos-delay="100"  style="position:absolute;width:100%; z-index:1 display:flex; ">
    <img id="dreambigimg1" src="assets/webstuff/indbg1.png" style="height: 300px; width: 300px;transform: translateX(45%)">
    <img id="dreambigimg2" src="assets/webstuff/indbg2.png" style="height: 400px; width: 400px;transform: translateY(100%) translateX(25%)">
    <img id="dreambigimg3" src="assets/webstuff/indbg3.png" style="height: 300px; width: 300px;transform: translateY(-20%) translateX(-20%)">
    <img id="dreambigimg4" src="assets/webstuff/indbg4.png" style="height: 300px; width: 300px;transform: translateY(100%) translateX(-5%)">
    <img id="dreambigimg5" src="assets/webstuff/indbg5.png" style="height: 250px; width: 250px;transform: translateX(10%)">
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```css
#dbi {
  filter: brightness(30%)
}
```

It looks fine on my laptop and monitor screens, but it doesn't resize and takes up the whole space on phone

Comment: Have you considered sizing in terms of viewport dimensions? vmin would seem to be the most suitable in this case.

Comment: how would I position them tho

Comment: Depends on where you want them on different viewports with different aspect ratios. I suspect but don’t know, that % or vw/vh would be the units to use. What are the designs for different viewports?

Comment: Im not sure about the designs for different viewports, but I know when I move to a laptop screen, the images seem smaller in the ratio with the text and also translated up

Comment: And this is after I changed to %. Here is my updated code: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=uzvh3AiROE

Comment: You need to know what you want it to look like on different viewport aspect ratios.

Comment: Please put runnable snippets into your question, not on an external site.